# How can I achieve this SQL QUERY in sequelize (multiple joins and multiple AND/OR)

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've been struggling to achieve this (below SQL statement) in sequelize for a while now with no luck. I initially had to make separate sequelize queries to get the data but that just posed many limitations.

```
    `SELECT "Documents".* FROM "Documents"
  INNER JOIN "AccessTypes"
    ON "AccessTypes"."id" = "Documents"."accessTypeId"
  INNER JOIN "Users"
    ON "Users"."id" = "Documents"."userId"
  INNER JOIN "Departments"
    ON "Departments"."id" = "Users"."departmentId"
  WHERE
    (("AccessTypes".name != 'private'
      AND "Departments"."id" = ${req.decoded.departmentId})
    OR "Users".id = ${req.decoded.id})
      AND ("Documents"."title" ILIKE '%${searchQuery}%'
        OR "Documents"."content" ILIKE '%${searchQuery}%'`
```

This is as far as I got

```
    var dbQuery = {
    where: {
      $or: [
        {
          title: {
            $iLike: `%${searchQuery}%`
          }
        },
        {
          content: {
            $iLike: `%${searchQuery}%`
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    include: [{
      model: db.Users,
      where: { departmentId: req.decoded.departmentId }
    },
    {
      model: db.AccessTypes,
      where: { name: { $ne: 'private'}}
    }]
  };

  db.Documents.findAll(dbQuery)
```

I still need to fetch another set of documents based on the userId supplied. I feel the way to go will be to perform an 'Include' within an '$or' statement. however my research so far leads me to believe that's not possible.

Here are my models
Access Types

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const AccessTypes = sequelize.define('AccessTypes', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      isUnique: true
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: (models) => {
        // associations can be defined here
        AccessTypes.hasMany(models.Documents, {
          foreignKey: 'accessTypeId',
          onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        });
      }
    }
  });
  return AccessTypes;
};
```

Users

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Users = sequelize.define('Users', {
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    firstname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    lastname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        isEmail: true
      }
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    roleId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 3
    },
    departmentId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: (models) => {
        // associations defined here
        Users.belongsTo(models.Roles, {
          onDelete: 'CASCADE',
          foreignKey: 'roleId'
        });
        Users.belongsTo(models.Departments, {
          onDelete: 'CASCADE',
          foreignKey: 'departmentId'
        });

        Users.hasMany(models.Documents, {
          as: 'documents',
          foreignKey: 'userId',
          onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        });
      }
    }, ...
```

Departments

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Departments = sequelize.define('Departments', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      isUnique: true
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: (models) => {
        // associations can be defined here
        Departments.hasMany(models.Users, {
          foreignKey: 'departmentId',
          onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        });
      }
    }
  });
  return Departments;
};
```

and Documents

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Documents = sequelize.define('Documents', {
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    content: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    accessTypeId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 1
    },
    docTypeId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: (models) => {
        // associations can be defined here
        Documents.belongsTo(models.Users, {
          foreignKey: 'userId',
          as: 'user',
          onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        });
        Documents.belongsTo(models.DocumentTypes, {
          foreignKey: 'docTypeId',
          onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        });
        Documents.belongsTo(models.AccessTypes, {
          foreignKey: 'accessTypeId',
          onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        });
      }
    }
  });
  return Documents;
};
```

Any Pointers Will be greatly appreciated
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite complex query (in Sequelize way of course), so you need to build it differently than you did. You should use functions like [`sequelize.col()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#colcol-sequelizecol), [`sequelize.where()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#whereattr-comparator-logic-sequelizewhere), [`sequelize.or()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#orargs-sequelizeor) and [`sequelize.and()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#andargs-sequelizeand). Moreover, in order to include the `Departments` model in the query, you need to use nested `include` statement in the options object of the `findAll` query. You can nest the includes as much as you want.

```
where: sequelize.and(
    sequelize.or(
        sequelize.and(
            sequelize.where(sequelize.col('AccessTypes.name'), '!=', 'private'),
            sequelize.where(sequelize.col('Departments.id'), '=', req.decoded.departmentId)
        ),
        sequelize.where(sequelize.col('Users.id'), '=', req.decoded.id)
    ),
    sequelize.or(
        { title: { $iLike: `%${searchQuery}%` } },
        { content: { $iLike: `%{searchQuery}%` } }
    )
),
include: [
    {
        model: db.Users,
        include: [ db.Departments ]
    },
    {
        model: db.AccessTypes
    }
]
```

You need to briefly get through documentation of above mentioned functions. In a short, `col()` creates a proper column selection basing on model name and field, `where()` creates `WHERE` statement with use of three attributes - column, condition (comparator) and logic, `or()` creates `OR` statement and `and()` creates `AND` statement. Both `or()` and `and()` can obtain multiple arguments that allows you to create complex statements, like yours.

Comment: Wow, this looks great. I'm yet to apply it though but I'm confident it'll work. Thanks a lot

Comment: I was able to use this. Worked like a charm Thanks again